# Cannot inherit from final '~Binding'

Tags: android, android-studio

データバインディング時に自動生成される~BindingImplから~Bindingを継承する際に、「Cannot inherit from final '~Binding'」が発生していてデータバインドができません。
解決方法ご存じの方いるでしょうか。